# Galois Group of an irreducible cubic

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I need to prove that if the Galois group of an irreducible cubic over $\mathbb Q$ is $\{id, \sigma, \sigma^2\}$, then all the roots of the cubic are real.

How do I even start this?

Comment: Is this statement true? What about $x^3 - x - 1$?

Comment: @tacos: the Galois group of that polynomial is $S_3$.

Comment: @Breezy: try proving the contrapositive.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan oops.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan i am still uber confused

Answer (score 13):

Hint:  If $\alpha = a + bi$ is a complex but nonreal root of a cubic polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then so is $\overline{\alpha} = a - bi$.  Consider complex conjugation and show that it belongs to the Galois group of the splitting field of the polynomial.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a very much ok approach to the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Hints:

1. A cubic polynomial with real coefficients has at least one real root.
2. If you join that one real root you get a cubic extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. [Edit: extending the hints] Show that the field $K$ is contained in the splitting field, and also that $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.
3. Given that the Galois group is known to be cyclic of order three, deduce that $K$ is the splitting field, and thus all the roots are real.

Comment: A cubic with all roots in R\Q may have S3 or A3 for its Galois group?

Comment: @Breezy: True, but what does that have to do with the question? You were given that the Galois group is $A_3$. Anyway, I expanded the set of hints a bit.

Comment: we haven't learned what A3 is.

Comment: It's cyclic of order three, so...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You say "If you join that one real root you get a cubic extension". But, what if the real root is already in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @AlJebr It was given that the cubic is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. Therefore it won't have rational zeros.